# Compact set in Hilbert Space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let {$\delta_n$} be a sequence of positive numbers, and let S be the set of all $x\in H$ of the form $$x=\sum\limits_{1}^\infty c_n u_n$$
where $|c_n| \leq \delta_n$. Prove that $S$ is compact iff $$\sum\limits_{1}^\infty\delta_n^2<\infty$$

I know this is a more general type of proof, from the hilbert cube compactness proof. But I am not sure what the condition $$\sum\limits_{1}^\infty\delta_n^2<\infty$$ has to do with the proof. If someone could provide a proof or some hints, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Is $(u_n)$ an orthonormal (Schauder) basis?

Comment: Yes it is an orthonormal basis

Answer (score 2):

We want to use the fact that compactness in a metric space is true if and only if every sequence has a convergent subsequence.

To show one direction of implication, consider the sequence
$$
x_k = \sum_{n=1}^k \delta_n u_n
$$
and show that it has no convergent subsequence.

---

For the converse, consider an arbitrary sequence
$$
x_{k} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n^{k,0} u_n
$$
we can find a subsequence
$$
x_{k,1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n^{k,1} u_n
$$
such that the sequence 
$
c_1^{k,1} u_1
$
converges.  From this sequence, we can extract a subsequence
$$
x_{k,2} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n^{k,2} u_n
$$
such that the sequence 
$
c_1^{k,2} u_1 + c_2^{k,2} u_2 
$
converges.  For an arbitrary $m$, we can find a subsequence of $x_{k,m-1}$ such that the sequence
$$
\sum_{n=1}^m c_n^{k,m} u_n
$$
converges.  Now, show that the sequence $(x_{k,k})_{k=1}^\infty$ is a convergent subseqence of $(x_k)_{k=1}^\infty$.

Comment: To show one direction of implication, consider the sequence
$$
x_k = \sum_{n=1}^k \delta_n u_n
$$
and show that it has **no convergent subsequence.** Why?

Comment: A metric space is compact if and only if every sequence in the space has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: So why show that the seq above has none?

Comment: Because it would show that the metric space $S$ fails this condition, which in turn implies that $S$ is not compact.

Comment: How does one go about showing this?

Comment: Showing what exactly?  That the sequence has no convergent subsequence?

Comment: yes that it has no convergent subseq.

Comment: Try something simpler first. How would you show that $x_k = \sum_{n=1}^k 1/n$ (the sequence in $\Bbb R$) has no convergent subsequence? Try to extend the same process.